# kendo ui mvvm: dynamically update multiselect datasource inside View Model' s change event

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui

I have a View with two multiselect widgets whose values (region_edu_admin, edu_admin) and datasources (region_edu_admins_ds, edu_admins_ds) are binded (through data-bind) to a ViewModel. Inside region_edu_admin's change event (regionEduAdminChanged) i am trying to reload edu_admin's widget datasource, that is edu_admins_ds, by using the set method. Though i do get inside newEduAdminsDS(), the datasource does not get reloaded. Any ideas on what i' m missing here would be much appreciated! You can see the code below:

/* View Model */

```
var LabsSearchVM = kendo.observable({
  region_edu_admins_ds: newRegionEduAdminsDS(),
  edu_admins_ds: newEduAdminsDS(), 
  region_edu_admin: "",
  edu_admin: "",    
  regionEduAdminChanged: function(e) {
    this.set("edu_admins_ds", newEduAdminsDS());
  }
});
```

/* View */

```
<label for="region_edu_admin">Περιφερειακή Διεύθυνση Εκπαίδευσης</label>
<select id="sl_region_edu_admin" 
        name="region_edu_admin"
        data-role="multiselect"
        data-auto-bind="false"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        data-text-field="name"
        data-value-field="name"
        data-bind="source: region_edu_admins_ds, value: region_edu_admin, events: {change : regionEduAdminChanged }"
        data-filter="contains"
        multiple="multiple">                    
</select>
<label for="edu_admin">Διεύθυνση Εκπαίδευσης</label>
<select id="sl_edu_admin" 
        name="edu_admin"
        data-role="multiselect"
        data-auto-bind="false"
        data-text-field="name"
        data-value-field="name"
        data-bind="source: edu_admins_ds, value: edu_admin"
        data-filter="contains"
        multiple="multiple">
</select>
```

/* newEduAdminsDS() function */

```
function newEduAdminsDS() {    
  var edu_admins_ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "api/edu_admins",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
      }
    },
    schema: {
      data: "data",
      model: {
        id: "edu_admin_id",
        fields: {
          edu_admin_id: { editable: false },
          name: { editable: false },
          region_edu_admin_id: { editable: false },
          region_edu_admin: { editable: false }
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return edu_admins_ds;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to re-create the DataSource. All you need to do is tell it to `read()` again to reload the data. Change the `regionEduAdminChanged` function in your observable to this:

```
regionEduAdminChanged: function(e) {
  this.edu_admins_ds.read();
}
```